# How to read binary file and write to .txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file.binary like this:

`3388AB88FFAC88BBAC88hello88`

I want to export it to a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("binary_file", "rb") as bin_file, open("text_file.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(bin_file.read().decode())
```